# Importing data from two files into neo4j using LOAD CSV

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to import data into neo4j using LOAD CSV

The resource file contains names of all the nodes I need to create

```
resource1
resource2
resource3
```

In another file I have all the properties of that resource

```
resource1,name,xyz
resource1,year,1920
resource1,age,100
resource2,length,300
resource2,age,30
```

I Managed to load the nodes into neo4j but how do I import the second file so that I can add the data to that particular node as properties, I tried setting the key dynamically

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///infobox.csv' AS line
MERGE (:Node{line[1]:line[2]})
```

neo4j doesn't allow setting the key dynamically?

How do I solve this?

Comment: What is `resource1`, `resource2`, etc? Is it a property value?  If true, what is the key?

Answer (score 1):

Natively, Neo4j doesn't allow setting the key dynamically. But you can install [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) use `apoc.create.setProperty` to do this.

Try something like:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///infobox.csv' AS line
// match the node by resource1, resource2, etc
MATCH(node:Node{resource_id : line[0]}) 
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(node, line[1], line[2])
RETURN *
```

*Note: Remember to install APOC procedures according the version of Neo4j you are using. Take a look in the [Version Compatibility Matrix](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_version_compatibility_matrix).*